# iSCSI Target drive turned RAW format

Tags: iscsi, raw-disk, windows-storage-server

I have an iSCSI Target drive that was working fine after creation for a few days. After i copied about 40GB of data to it i lost access to the drive. the file system had changed to RAW and windows wanted me to format. I did not format but was able to convert it back to NTFS and run CHKDSK which restored all my files.

Google search tells me how to fix it but i'm very concerned about what caused this problem. I have not been able to find any explanation of what could have caused it. Does anyone have any ideas ? Before moving my 150 TB of production data i really want to know.

Thanks

Comment: If you can't tell what went wrong, there probably would not be any other person in this world who could. Try to reproduce the condition - if you can, work with that and feel free to post a more detailed problem description. If you can't, consider it an obscure bug. Also, it is worth mentioning what exactly you have done to get the partition back since it gives some clues about what has been broken in the first place

Comment: i ran CONVERT E: /fs:ntfs which told me it's already an NTFS partition. Then i ran chkdsk which fixed a whole series of issues and drive works ok again

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer and give it the checkmark so that future visitors don't think you're still waiting for help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ran CONVERT E: /fs:ntfs which told me it's already an NTFS partition. Then i ran chkdsk which fixed a whole series of issues and drive works ok again